# Ability to apply a colored area for a plotted date period

Tags: highcharts

In this example [JFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/qwfZ9/1546/). I want to apply a colored area for a plotted/selected date period. For example, if I select points 1 to 10, the background of these points should be highlighted.

```
var $report = $('#report');

// create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    events: {
        selection: function(event) {
            if (event.xAxis) {
                var min = Math.ceil( event.xAxis[0].min ),
                    max = Math.ceil( event.xAxis[0].max ),
                    data = this.series[0].data,
                    list = [];

                $('#report').empty();

                for(i=min; i<max; i++)
                    list.push('<li>x: '+data[i].x+', y: '+data[i].y+'</li>');

                $('#report').append( list.join('') );

            }
            return false;
        }
    },
    zoomType: 'x'
},
xAxis: {
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,     54.4]        
}]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add the `PlotBand` in your `selection` event.

```
 chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
                chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                    from: min,
                    to: max,
                    color: '#FCFFC5',
                    id: 'plot-band-1'
                });
```

Example **[`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/qwfZ9/2892/)**. **[`API`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotBand%28%29)** for your reference.

Hope this helps.